# AngularJS fade-in div element when requirement is met with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like this fade class div to show on the page with a slow fade-in effect when the ng-show requirement has been met. In jQuery I could do this in a jiffy but it's proving difficult in Angular due to lack of working examples. Here is the working code:

Here is the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="container" style="padding-top:30px">
    <user-info-card></user-info-card>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `script.js`:

```
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        name: 'Luke Skywalker',
        address: {
          street: 'PO Box 123',
          city: 'Secret Rebel Base',
          planet: 'Yavin 4'
        },
        friends: [
        'Han',
        'Leia',
        'Chewbacca'
        ],
        rank: 'scout',
        score: 27
    } 
});
angular.module('app').directive('userInfoCard', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: "userInfoCard.html",
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.knightMe = function(user) {
                if (user.score > 25) {
                  user.rank = 'miner';
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Here is the template file `userInfoCard.html` loaded by the directive:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{user.name}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ng-show='!!user.address'>
            <h4>Address:</h4>
            {{user.address.street}} <br />
            {{user.address.city}}<br />
            {{user.address.planet}}
        </div> <br /> 

        <h4>Friends:</h4>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='friend in user.friends'>
                {{friend}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            Rank: {{user.rank}}
        </div><br>
        <div ng-show="user.score >= 25" ng-class="ng-show" class="fade">
            <span>Congratulations, you have the ranked up! Click the button below to claim your new rank now.</span><br />
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="knightMe(user)">Knight Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And last but not least, the `style.css`:

```
.fade.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade.ng-show {
    transition: 0.5s linear all;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

So in a nutshell, when the user score is more than 25, which it is in this case, I would like that fade class div to load in a gentle fade-in fashion. It's loading now fine but I'm not sure how to add the effect. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to animate ngShow/Hide elements you first need to include ngAnimate module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Then all you need just a few little CSS rules:

```
.fade {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fade.ng-hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: all .5s linear;
    display: block !important;
}
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/qHcMEL2Da5Fome7nUenf?p=info

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I appreciate and grasp your concept but would you know how to create the same effect on page load? So basically, ng-show test passes and when the user comes to the page, the div fades in slowly.

Comment: Check updated demo, you can still do it with just CSS.

Comment: I feel it's worth pointing out that the expression is present in the DOM and that this could possibly be cloaked in future versions? Perhaps this is already possible? http://pasteboard.co/1L481WXm.png

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by the following step:

**Step1:** First add the library/package of angular-animate.js

**Step2:** Then include the library in the module `angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);`

**Step3** You can manipulate the UI like   `angular.element(element).fadeIn(1000, doneFn);`

Check the documentation for Reference :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: Do I really have to use jQuery? Is there no other possibility in AngularJS, or is AngularJS just not designed to load a div with a slow fade-in effect?

Comment: you can re-write it as angular.element(element) OR simply element.fadeIn,Check i have update the jQuery Part

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);` otherwise animations wont work.
You may also wantto add [Angular Animate](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-animate.js)